# Windows 8.1 drivers?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8.1, lenovo-laptop, chipset

This question is related to a laptop (Lenovo G560) with Intel HM55 chipset + Integrated Intel HD graphics w/ shared video memory.

I wanted to know if Windows 8.1 will run on it (At present it is running on Windows 7 home basic). The Lenovo site does not have a chipset driver for Windows 8 but there is one for Windows 7.

Windows 7 has following drivers -

1. **Intel Chipset driver for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit)**
2. Intel Management Engine Interface for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit)

Windows 8 has only -

1. Intel Management Engine Interface Driver for Microsoft Windows 8

Does Windows 8 does not need chipset driver? Does it have inbuilt driver for this chipset?

Comment: Windows 8 does need one its just not been released by your OEM.

Comment: will the default driver present in windows work? What are my options? The OEM site has other drivers but only the chipset driver is missing - http://support.lenovo.com/en_IN/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT072731

Comment: The generic driver can indeed work for certain features.

Comment: So what features will be disbaled.

Comment: Not possible to predict.

Comment: i just want good screen resolution, font rendering and day to day functionaliy. No high fi games etc

Comment: If you want all that then you need a Windows 8.1 Intel driver because of the display model driver changes anything else won't provide all of that.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification. Do you know where i can get the intel drivers for this cipset. It not on my OEM site and i cant find it on intel's either. Thanks.